Setting up a complex/custom .htaccess redirect rule
I am trying to set up a custom rule for redirecting all URLs within a folder to a different path on a different domain.
I want ALL files within this URL structure:
https://olddomain.com/folder/uploads
to be forwarded to the SAME file URL within this URL structure:
https://newdomain.com/launch/folder/uploads
the setup includes multiple nested folders within the uploads folder.
Expanded examples:
https://olddomain.com/folder/uploads/folder1/file.pdf
should be forwarded to
https://newdomain.com/launch/folder/uploads/folder1/file.pdf
and
https://olddomain.com/folder/uploads/folder2/file1.pdf
should be forwarded to
https://newdomain.com/launch/folder/uploads/folder2/file1.pdf
If it matters, both domains are on the same server/account.
I have looked at all the similar threads on stack overflow to no avail. None of the examples worked for me, even when I edited for my use case.
Thanks in advance!

This sounds pretty straight forward, actually... You say that none of the examples worked. You see, since the examples here on SO definitely do work the question is: why don't they work in your specific case? There is little sense in us writing another such example, it would be the same as the other few hundred examples. You you would make the same experience with it, right? So we have to find the difference in your situation. Which is something we cannot do, only you have knowledge over that.

Please take a bit of time and revise your question. There is an "edit" button below it, use it ... Please add two or three examples of what you actually tried and explain why you say that it "did not work for you". Be precise : what does that actually mean? What happened if you made a test request? What did your http server's log files show? Where and how did you implement those rules?

Ensure that mod_rewrite is enabled on your Apache server.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/uploads/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/launch/folder/uploads/%1 [R=301,L]

Note:
If the .htaccess rules are not taking effect, you might need to ensure that AllowOverride All is set for the directory in your Apache configuration file. You can check this in your Apache configuration file.
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

If you change your Apache configuration, don’t forget to restart the Apache service.
